# Differential equations in function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Equations (1) : $xy'+(1-x)y=1$  let $z=xy+1$

determine and solve the differential equation (2) whose general solution is the function $z$ 
.

-determine the general solution of (1)

Comment: What would (2) be?

Comment: The second equation whose z is its general solution

Answer (score 1):

If $z=xy+1$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dz}{dx} &=& \frac{d}{dx}\left(xy+1\right) \\
              &=& y+x\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{eqnarray}
Now:
\begin{eqnarray}
x\frac{dy}{dx}+y-xy       &=& 1 \\
\implies x\frac{dy}{dx}+y &=& 1+xy\\
\implies \frac{dz}{dx}   &=& z
\end{eqnarray}
Now you solve this equation for $z$ and then change back the variables to $x$ and $y$ at the end.

Comment: Didn't understand ?

Answer (score -1):

Compute $z'=y+xy'=y+1-(1-x)y=z$

So the general solution of the above equation (call it eqn (2))is

$$z(x)=z(0)e^x=e^x$$

because $z(0)=1$. Solving then for $y$:

$$y(x)=\frac{z-1}{x}=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Comment: Z' isn't equal to x'y+y'x ?

Comment: And $x'=1$ because we are deriving relative to the variable $x$

Comment: How can I improve my knowledge in differential equations lesson